# How to capture subgroup of capture

Tags: java, regex

I have some text as follows:

```
Postprandial Data

Reflux Episode Activity (Impedance)
            Total   Normal

    Postprandial Analysis Settings

Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)
```

I would like to find and delete everything before `Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)`

I am managing to unfortunately delete `Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)` with the following code. How can I keep it? I have tried both `group(0)` and `group(1)`.

```
Pattern goPP = Pattern.compile("(Postprandial Data.*)Symptom Correlation to Reflux",Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher goPP_pattern = goPP.matcher(s);
            //This splits the original document into the Main stuff and the postprandial stuff so extraction should be more straightforward
            String PPStr="";
                        while (goPP_pattern.find()) {
                   for (String df:goPP_pattern.group(1).split("\n")){
                        PPStr=PPStr+df+"\n";
                    s = s.replace(df,"");
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: use **[this](https://regex101.com/r/tX8qK5/1)** regex

Comment: **[this](http://ideone.com/f02B6K)** is the output you want??

Comment: Typo omitted the Postprandial data line. @rock each line ends up having its whitespace removed. If I try your regex with Postprandial Data.*(?=Symptom Correlation to Reflux)",Pattern.DOTALL) it doesn't capture however.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific what you want? do you want to capture data also after `Postprandial data`?

Comment: I have edited the question. I want to remove everything from and including Postprandial Data to anything before (but not including) "Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)"

Comment: You can use `String repl = str.replaceAll("(?s)Postprandial Data.*(?=Symptom Correlation to Reflux \\(Impedance\\))", "");`

Comment: Why use a regex at all? Use [`input.substring(input.indexOf(text_to_find))`](https://ideone.com/ePRcI9)

Comment: @anubhava- the string Symptom Correlation to Reflux is still deleted.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thats a nice solution although there is more text above PostPrandial Data (not shown for the sake of MCVE)

Comment: is https://regex101.com/r/tX8qK5/2 what you want?

Comment: The regex works as a regex (as does mine) but I think the question is more about which group to delete- how can I put the phrase "Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)" in the non deleted group?

Comment: @SebastianZeki: The rule - I have been answering the same questions several days on end - is the same: match what you do not need to keep, and match and *capture* what you need to later restore the text with the backreference. Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/pD1uT8/1), or a more sophisticated and less efficient [this](https://regex101.com/r/pD1uT8/2).

Comment: I dont think the regex is the problem. It's really a question about retrieving subgroups I think

Comment: @SebastianZeki The best way will be to use matcher and concatenate whatever you want finally

Comment: @rock321987: The question is very unclear. The question states that *I would like to find and delete everything before Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)* - in fact, no, OP needs to remove everything between the `Postprandial Data` and `Symptom Correlation to Reflux (Impedance)`, however, the input string just does not contain that substring.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just realized that..I deleted my comment..

Comment: @rock321987: [See this demo](http://ideone.com/c76o6B)

Comment: @anubhava actually my input did not have `Postprandial Data`..sorry that you were bothered for my mistake

Comment: Hi @anubhava can you post as an answer. I really have no idea why but I've gone with the string replace all answer. I think my capturing groups was complicating things but seems to be working now

Comment: I think it will be unfair to @rock321987 if I post an answer. I think he can modify his answer to suit this requirement.

Comment: @anubhava thanks..I have modified it

Answer (score 3):

This regex will suffice your need

```
(?s)Postprandial Data.*?(?=Symptom Correlation to Reflux \(Impedance\))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX8qK5/3)**

Java Code

```
System.out.println(ln.replaceAll("(?s)Postprandial Data.*?(?=Symptom Correlation to Reflux \\(Impedance\\))", ""));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/f02B6K)**

Comment: Why use `[\s\S]` in Java? There is a DOTALL option. Add `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern. Note `[\s\S]` is slower than `.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew habituated of using it

Comment: The \s\S causes the end result to have all whitespace removed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nice..+1